# What's wrong with my Pear tree?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, plant-health, fruit-trees, plant-care

Is it Pear blight? What's the best way to fix it? 
[image]

[image]

Comment: anything odd to be seen under the leaves?

Comment: @bamboo, I have added a photo of the back of a leaf

Answer (score 1):

You're in the UK, so unless we've now acquired a range of new fungal infections here that I don't know about yet, this might be Pear Leaf Blister Mite in its advanced stages. The other alternative is canker, but the only hint I can see that it might be that is what appears to be a blackened, shiny shoot protruding from the woody branch lower down from the leaves in the second photo... usually with canker, the evidence for it is on the wood, not so much the leaves. Examine the tree closely, particularly the woody parts, to see if there's any oozing or cracked, swollen areas. Info on problems with pears in the UK here https://www.gardenfocused.co.uk/fruitarticles/pears/pest.php